# Porting .bashrc function from python 2.7 to python 3

Tags: bash, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hi would somebody please explain to port this function from python2.7 to 3 as i have bee unable to do so

```
function cpuusg(){
    echo print `top -n 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d$" " -f10 | tail -n +8 | head -n -1 | paste -sd+ | bc`/ `nproc` | python
}
```

Comment: Have you tried piping out to python3 instead of python?

Comment: Python 3's `print` requires parentheses. Also, in Python 2 the `/` division operator does integer division; in Python 3 it does real division.

Comment: Why would you pipe it to `python`, you can do simple arithmetic expressions in `bash`. What error are you getting when you `| python3`?

Comment: @AChampion: bash doesn't do floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @KeithThompson true, but `bc` which is in the tool chain does.

Comment: What are you trying to compute, exactly? Adding up a particular column from `top`, where the number of rows you get is dependent on the size of your terminal window and almost certainly does not reflect all active processes, is probably not the way to do it.

Comment: `head -n -1`, by the way, only outputs a single line, rendering the following call to `paste` meaningless.

Comment: I am trying to compute CPU usage however I did not come up with the initial command I am simply trying to port it to Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring (almost) any other issue with this function, the problem is that the `print` statement that is being constructed and passed to Python needs to be converted to a call to a function.

```
function cpuusg() {
    numerator=$(top -n 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f10 | tail -n +8 | head -n -1 | paste -sd+ | bc)
    denominator=$(nproc)
    echo "print($numerator / $denominator)" | python
}
```